# Loading 200 GWT ListBoxes is slow

Tags: java, performance, gwt, listbox

I'm a relative newbie to GWT development.  I've inherited a GWT web app that currently loads almost 200 GWT ListBoxes with some data (~20 items).  Loading this data is very slow.  Is there a way I can "bind" all of the ListBoxes to one data object which in turn is loaded with the data?  Would the Editor framework help me out?  I'd prefer not to redesign the UI but I may have to if necessary.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you look at the Timeline in your preferred browser and confirm where exactly the slowdown is?

Comment: Loading 200 itmes in listbox ,Is a punishment to end user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three strategies I recommend for big forms:

1* use deferred execution to keep the UI responsive.

2* preload the view as soon as possible.

3* use html templates or safeHtml

**1)**

```
private void setListBoxValues(final Map<String, String> theValues) {
        Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {
            @Override
            public void execute() {
                clear();
                for (Entry<String, String> entry : theValues.entrySet()) {
                    box.addItem(entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

**2)**

If the user has to go through some page before going to the form you can already create your view (using new ...()) and call the method which loads your listboxes before they actually have to be displayed. For some of our views we even preload them at login time, so displaying them to the user is close to 'immediate'.

Another thing I do when some page/widget as to appear a unknown bug large number of times on the same page, is to create a stack of prealoaded views/widgets, and pass them to my presenter upon request. The presenter can then display them immediately.

**3)**

If the listbox content is always the same you can use SafeHtml or Html templates to directly generate HTML and pass it to your listboxes. Here's and example which will generate the code for a button. I've never used it specifically to improve performances but I guess it'll be quicker.

```
protected interface Templates extends SafeHtmlTemplates {
    @SafeHtmlTemplates.Template("<button type=\"button\" value=\"{0}\" tabindex=\"-1\">{1}</button>")
    SafeHtml button(String value, String label);
}
private static Templates templates = GWT.create(Templates.class);
public void render() {
    SafeHtml rendered = templates.button("myValue", "myLabel");
    // ... then inject HTML in some HTMLPanel
}
```